# Knockout.js foreach as element to new ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to do the next thing:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: elementsVM.elementsList, as: 'element' }">
   <div data-bind="with: new ElementViewModel(element).getElementDetailsByLang(langFilter)">
        <h3 data-bind="html: ElementTitle"></h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when `with: new ElementViewModel(element).getElementDetailsByLang(langFilter)` is called, the `element` that ends as parameter to `ElementViewModel(Element)` it's the entire collection from the foreach binding (`elementsVM.elementsList`) instead of the current element from the foreach iteration.
elementsVM is an ElementsViewModel:

```
function ElementsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.ElementsList = ko.observableArray();

    self.getElementsForCategory = function(categoryId) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

And the ElementViewModel looks like this:

```
function ElementViewModel(Element) {
    var self = this;

    self.ElementModel = new ElementModel(Element);

    self.getElementDetailsByLang = function (lang) {
        return ko.computed(function () {                
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you do:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: elementsVM.elementsList }">
   <div data-bind="with: new ElementViewModel($data).getElementDetailsByLang(langFilter)">
        <h3 data-bind="html: ElementTitle"></h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

Your alternative is to use a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), if that doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot use $data because I have nested foreach. I will try to use the custom binding. Thanks!

Comment: I know that custom binding is becoming my "go to" response on here, but it is pretty helpful for a lot of situations!